# PHP Session Variables Request Time

Tags: php, session

I was wondering wether it makes a difference in speed to save PHP SESSION Variables at the top of a script as Variables or just use the SESSION Variables through the entire script. e.g.

```
$_SESSION['bar'];

...

<p><?php echo $_SESSION['bar'] ?></p>
<p><?php echo $_SESSION['bar'][0] ?></p>
```

Or as explained above: Save the SESSION Variable first and then access that variable instead.

```
$bar = $_SESSION['bar'];

...

<p><?php echo $bar ?></p>
<p><?php echo $bar[0] ?></p>
```

Does it make any difference? Is PHP Requesting the SESSION Variables every single time from the server again?

Comment: It won't make any noticable performance difference. If you get actual proven performance problems you can start profiling. From a code maintenance point of view you probably want to save it into a variable if it is used more often so once the key changes you don't have to change it all over the place but only once.

Comment: That's one of my many petpyves... what I mean, I just don't understand why anyone would create a copy of a variable that already exists. Really, to me, that doesn't make much sense. You know, I have questioned many people who do that and I have to say I have never been given a truly justifiable reason why they do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you do these session read/write operations millions of times (e.g. in a loop) you shouldn't be concerned with such micro optimizations. Even if you do them like that, I still think that PHP writes to session whenever that session is closed (not 100% sure about this last one).

Remember that [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization). :)

On a more serious note:

- It's always recommended to move code that's used more than once into a variable or a helper function ([DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))
- By creating a helper function or a "wrapper" class for accessing low level services like Sessions, your code becomes "future proof" and not bound to an implementation. If in the future you decide to replace the storage engine from Session to, e.g, Cookies or Redis, you just change the helper class and the rest of the code keeps working. In other words, try to practice the [Orthogonality principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality_(programming)).